# Аналог combinable (Microsoft PPL) в PLINQ?

Tags: c#, plinq

Необходимо заменить Microsoft PPL на PLINQ. В коде используется `combinable`. Я точно знаю, что в PLINQ существует аналог.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Похоже, вам нужен метод [`Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.parallelenumerable.aggregate.aspx). [Пример использования `combinable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728079.aspx), выводящий сумму простых чисел:

```
combinable<int> sum;
parallel_for_each(begin(a), end(a), [&](int i) {
   sum.local() += (is_prime(i) ? i : 0);
});
prime_sum = sum.combine(plus<int>());
```

С использованием `Aggregate` выглядит так:

```
var primeSum = a.AsParallel().Aggregate(
    // инициализируем начальное значение
    0, 
    // выполняем суммирование параллельно (аналог local())
    (subtotal, item) => subtotal + (IsPrime(item) ? item : 0),
    // получаем общую сумму (аналог combine())
    (total, subtotal) => total + subtotal,
    // отдаем сумму без изменений
    (final) => final);
```

Comment: Человек, выдавший мне задание, сказал, что это не aggregate. т.е. через aggregate то же можно и ваш ответ однозначно является верным, однако есть еще что то, что "состоит из двух слов" (это единственное, что он вспомнил).

Comment: @user3239600 в принципе того же самого можно достичь с помощью `Parallel.ForEach`. Но чего в угадайку-то играть?

Comment: @user3239600: У нас здесь, видите ли, обычно помогают решить проблему по программированию, а не прочитать мысли другого человека.